# Make HTTP POST request and save values in a database

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I am making a web API for a application. Except for all that I had made to the web API, I want to make an HTTP POST request to a link that will send me a response in XML. I had to send a request every 5 minutes in order to take the last values of the products. These values of the XML I want to put it in a database I order to have access to it. The database I will use is MySql and I make the API in C#. I had made the model of the XML through the http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/:

```
   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "dd")]
    public class Dd
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "dd_descr")]
        public string Dd_descr { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "dimos_descr")]
        public string Dimos_descr { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "nomos_descr")]
        public string Nomos_descr { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "address")]
    public class Address
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "fulladdress")]
        public string Fulladdress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "zipcode")]
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "dd")]
        public Dd Dd { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "product")]
    public class Product
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "company")]
    public class Company
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "priceentry")]
    public class Priceentry
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "station")]
        public string Station { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "product")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "timestamp")]
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "company")]
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "pricelist")]
    public class Pricelist
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "priceentry")]
        public List<Priceentry> Priceentry { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A part of the xml is:

```
  <pricelist>
    <priceentry>
      <station>2</station>
       <name> name </name>
         <address>
          <fulladdress> name </fulladdress>
           <zipcode>10442</zipcode>
            <dd>
             <code>A1010400</code>
             <dd_descr> name
             </dd_descr>
             <dimos_descr> name </dimos_descr>
             <nomos_descr> name </nomos_descr>
         </dd>
     </address>
    <product>
        <code>11</code>
        <description> name </description>
    </product>
    <price>1.558</price>
    <timestamp>1576649282267</timestamp>
    <company>
        <code>2</code>
        <name> name </name>
    </company>
</priceentry>
```

What I am asking is the following: what is the best way to accomplish what I have described

Comment: Why is your xml so many different layers?  You should design the database table first.  Then create your xml  so you only have one layer that is the table names with a list of properties that correspond to the columns in the table(s).